# TeamCity building C++ with Visual Studio Solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, teamcity

I have a small test project that I want to build with TeamCity. In TeamCity I have created a build step with runner type 'Visual Studio' solution. The problem is it is not building. The error I get is:

error C1069: cannot read compiler command line

Here a part of the build log:

```
[16:55:05]ClCompile
[16:55:05]CL
[16:55:05]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\CL.exe /c /ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /sdl /Od /Oy- /D WIN32 /D _DEBUG /D _LIB /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc120.pdb" /Gd /TP /analyze- /errorReport:queue UnitTest.cpp
[16:55:05]UnitTest.cpp
[16:55:05]c:\data\teamcity buildagent\work\d8c46b39964cb4dc\testlibrary\unittest.cpp(27, 0): error C1069: cannot read compiler command line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the space in the TeamCity build agent path:

c:\data**teamcity buildagent**\work\d8c46b39964cb4dc\testlibrary\unittest.cpp

There is a bug with the VS2013 compiler as documented here:

> http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/82304c15-37e2-4761-8928-0c67e074bf47/error-c1069-cannot-read-compiler-command-line-on-visual-studio-2013-rc?forum=vcgeneral

(Note, this is referring to the RC and could now be fixed)

Comment: After an update to VS2013 Update 3 the problem was resolved. Thnx.